# Конвертировать из List<Person> в Map<String, List<Person>>

Tags: java

Есть сущность Person. У нее есть геттер `getId()`.

Есть список этих сущностей `List<Person>.`

Как конвертировать из `List<Person>` в `Map<String, List<Person>>` так, что бы в качестве ключей были `Id`?

Т.е. сгрупировать `Person` по `Id`.

Comment: У вас id имеет тип String?

Comment: А это важно? Он у меня String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант на Stream API

```
Map<String, List<Person>> index = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId));
```

---

Вариант на коллекциях Java 8 без этих некрасивых `containsKey`

```
Map<String, List<Person>> index = new HashMap<>();
for (Person person : persons) {
    index.computeIfAbsent(person.getId(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(person);
}
```

Comment: Похоже я тут один неразумный, кто не хотел давать сразу код))

Comment: Ну это на самом деле рутинная задача, для которой хочется иметь готовый сниппет на SO )

Comment: проще gist.github.com)

Answer (score 5):

Самое простое и в лоб:

- итерировать список
- проверять за счет **[containsKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-)** есть ли уже в мапе такой ключ.
- если нет, то создать список в данном ключе и добавить объект
- если есть, то в уже созданный список добавить объект

---

Второй способ - использовать стримы Java8 и их методы, в частности группировки **[Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-)**

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю можно сделать как то так:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> mapPerson = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();

for(int i = 0; i<listPerson.size(); i++)
{
    String key = listPerson.get(i).getId();
    if (!mapPerson.containsKey(key))
    {
        mapPerson.put(key, new ArrayList<Person>());
    }
    mapPerson.get(key).add(listPerson.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Вариант** - используем `Map<String, Person>` (Если ID уникален)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, Person> personsMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Person person : persons) {
            personsMap.put(person.getId(), person);
        }
    }

    class Person {
        String id;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Вариант** - используем `Map<String, List<Person>>` (Если ID повторяются)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Person>> personsMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Person person : persons) {
            ArrayList<Person> personsList = personsMap.get(person.getId());

            if (personsList == null) {
                personsMap.put(person.getId(), new ArrayList<Person>());
            } else {
                personsList.add(person);
            }
        }
    }

    class Person {
        String id;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *сгрупировать `Person` по `Id`.* То есть `Id` может совпадать.

Answer (score -1):

если тип сущности Person

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();
List<Person> pers = new ArrayList<Person>();
int id = 0;
for(Person x : pers){
    String s = String.valueOf(id);
    map.put(s,x);
    id++;
}
```

Comment: не, тут ты кладешь (точнее пытаешься, ибо не сработает код) в мапу персону, а не список персон, сгруппированных по признаку

Comment: и вообще не ясно применение `id`

Comment: String s = String.valieOf(id); измените на String s = String.valueOf(id); опечатка видимо

Comment: Поддержу @АлексейШиманский, и ко всему прочему Ваш код работать не будет, вы кладете в Map Person, а перед этим заявляете new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();

Comment: Ерунда какая-то. Просили по id самого Person'а сложить.